Launching app with advertised shortcut triggers installer repair
An application I try to launch via its advertised shortcut always wants the installer MSI package (installer's repair function is triggered). I understand that this is due to some keyfiles missing. Is there a way to log which missing files trigger the repair?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
